# java regex: is it possible to find number of captures in a match without looping

Tags: java, regex

My code looks like this and it works fine for finding all the numbers in the matrix but it seems overly complicated to me.

```
String attr = "matrix(1 0 0 1 22.51 35)";
Pattern nums = Pattern.compile("(-*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*)");
Matcher m2 = nums.matcher(attr);
while(m2.find()) {
   Log.i(logTag, "s = " + m2.group(0));
}
```

I would like to allocate an array and then assign values to it so I could do something like:

```
Pattern nums = Pattern.compile("(-*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*)");
Matcher m2 = nums.matcher(attr);
String [] matches = new String[number_of_matches];
int index = 0;
while (m2.find()) {
    matches[index++] = m2.groups(0);
}
```

Is this possible?  I've looked for several hours and can't find anything like this in native java but I've found several pieces of example code to implement this functionality but it's something I'd expect to find in the regex library.
In PERL my code would look like:

```
$s = "matrix(1 0 0 1 22.51 35)";
@x = ($s =~ m{(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)}g);

x @x
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  22.51
5  35
```

Comment: What's your expected output, if the input is `matrix(1 0 0 1 22.51 35) foo(2 3 4 5.5)`

Comment: i think this https://regex101.com/r/kS7uN2/1 would help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no method for that functionality.
If it existed, it would do exactly what you describe: go over all matches and count them (and then reset to the beginning of the string)

If you really needed to know up-front, you could just write the counting function yourself.

But I would suggest that you use a `List` (such as an `ArrayList`) instead of an array; then you don't need to know the number of matches up-front, and the `List` interface is generally much much convenient to use than an array.

(Your Perl result also returns a variable-size list rather than a fixed-size array, if my rusty Perl knowledge is not mistaken)

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Bolwidt.  That's what I thought but wanted to verify it.  Yes -- the PERL does indeed return a variable size list which is really what I wanted since I have no idea how many elements this matrix will have until I parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `List` interface for these types of operations anyway.

```
Pattern nums = Pattern.compile("(-*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*)");
Matcher m2 = nums.matcher(attr);
List <String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m2.find()) {
    matches.add(m2.groups(0));
}
```

Comment: Oh and if you really need an array for some odd reason, `String[] matchArray = matches.toArray(new String[matches.size()]);`

Comment: Yep.  "my @x = ($s =~ m{(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)}g);" Return any captured matches from string s as list x.  I can do that umpteen different ways in Java but to my PERLish mind, they all seem rather convoluted.  I'm sure there are those who would say the same of my PERL.  However... Android doesn't support PERL so I'm using the available tools. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, with the find() you initiate scanning of your String of which you don't know much before hand. You can learn more only if the match succeeds, from the docs

> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods, and subsequent invocations of the
>   find() method will start at the first character not matched by this
>   match.